# Django - How to change dropdown form into table

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm creating an application in Django and I'm having an issue with iterating through options in a dropdown from a form in Django. I was wondering if anyone could be of assistance.

**detail.html**

```
{% for subject in subject_list %}
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table class='table table-borderless table-hover'>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ subject.subjectname }}
                        {% for field in form %}
                            {{ field.hidden }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" id="login-btn" class="btn">Create a new evaluation</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreateEvalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subjectname = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subject.objects, label='', empty_label="Choose subject..")

    class Meta:
        model = Evaluation
        fields = ['subjectname', ]
```

**models.py**

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subjectname = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Type the name of the subject.")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

Ideally we want it to look like on the picture below: 
**Note** that the picture is in danish and Fag = Subject, Opret ny evaluering = Create new evaluation and Se evaluering = View evaluation

[we want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4x1Q.png)

[we don't want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC0md.png)

Comment: You want the link "Create new evaluation" to directly submit a form? Or should it just open a new page where more data can be filled in?

Comment: It's a bit weird to submit a form that way...

Comment: Currently it works with whichever subject we choose will create an evaluation with that subject, so yes we want to submit the chosen subject here. We want a row with each subject and a button just like a regular dropdown but in table form.

Comment: strange way, it would be easier to just link to a form where the id of the subject is prefilled instead of actually submitting and creating an "empty" evaluation. But if that's what you really want, just render an <input type="submit"> field with the name `subjectname` of the field and the value of the id of the corresponding subject, that way your POST will contain the id of the subject for your `subject name` and your form will work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? When we render the form into our template we must be able to loop through the subject values into a table?

Comment: Yes you can do that: `form.subjectname.options` is a list of tuples of the field’s options. Each tuple is (<id>, <str>).

Comment: Okay thanks so how would I loop through a tuple in such an example?

Comment: Just loop through the list, each element is a tuple

Comment: So it would look like this?
`<tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                            {% for field in form %}
                            {{ field.fagnavn.option }}
                            {% endfor %}

                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>`

Comment: No you have to loop explicitly through form.subjectname.options. Why are you looping through form.fields? There’s only one field.

Comment: And I guess the loop should be outside of <tr> since you want one row per option

Comment: So I almost got it working like this:
`{% for option in form.fagnavn %}
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ option }}</td>
                        <td><button type="submit" id="login-btn" class="btn">Opret ny evaluering</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                {% endfor %}`

And it looks like this: [link](https://prnt.sc/pa654x)
But how do I get the button to work for each value?

Comment: I told you to make each submit an `<input type="submit">` instead of a button and to give them the attributes `name` and `value`. Also don't give them the same id, each should have a different id, e.g. `id="select-btn-{{ option.id }}`"

Comment: I can't still get it working with this:
`{% for option in form.fagnavn %}
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ option }} <input type="submit" value="Opret evaluering" name="fagnavn"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                {% endfor %}`
Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Actually no, use button and set its value to `{{ option.0 }}` and name to `"fagnavn"`. sorry. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_value.asp. With input you can't make the display different than the submit value.

Comment: And it should be `for option in form.fagnavn.options`

Comment: I can't iterate through `form.fagnavn.options` I get no output

Comment: oops. should be `form.fields.fagnavn.choices` of course. The choices are on the fields, not the bound fields.

Comment: Oh thanks! I'm almost done now. Because the first option is the "choose" option and I don't want that to be displayed.

[img](https://prnt.sc/pa7li6)

Comment: Or is there like a way to exclude the default option?

Comment: Django has some useful variables in a [for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for) loop. You can use `forloop.first` for example.

Comment: Okay thanks everything seems to be working now! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the help from the comments by changing my for loop and table to this:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table class='table table-borderless table-hover'>
                {% for option in form.fields.fagnavn.choices %}
                    {% if not forloop.first %}
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ option.1 }}</td>
                        <td><button value="{{ option.0 }}" name="fagnavn">Opret ny evaluering</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </form>
```

I gained access to the choices in the dropdown with `form.fields.fagnavn.choices` and excluded the default value of "choose value" with an if statement of `{% if not forloop.first %}`

And that's pretty much it.